# How can I disable Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository

Tags: git, msbuild

I installed VS 2022 Preview version and since that my build time is 10 seconds longer:

```
1>     9609 ms  Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository   1 calls
```

I do not want any git related build steps, can I disable this build task? In directory.build.props for instance? How?

Comment: The task is part of SourceLink and it appears that setting the `$(EnableSourceControlManagerQueries)` property to false will stop the task from being run -- but I'm just searching in the source. You will need to test if that property actually works and meets your need.

Comment: That worked, Thx @JonathanDodds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LocateRepository` task is not a standard MSBuild task. (See [MSBuild task reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference?view=vs-2022) for the standard tasks.) The task is part of [Source Link](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) which provides source code linkage metadata to support debugging.

From searching the Source Link source code, it appears that setting the `$(EnableSourceControlManagerQueries)` property to `false` will stop the task from being run.

The property is initialized in `Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.props` if a value is not already set, and is used in `Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.targets`. Overriding at the command line and overriding within a project file should both work.